# No Audio on Ubuntu-Mini-Remix

Tags: sound, alsa, nfs, ubuntu-minimal, squashfs

I'm using ubuntu-mini-remix to build a network-booting live OS which loads a remote desktop client and logs users into their virtual desktop environments.

I've gotten everything to work except the audio.

On top of Ubuntu-mini-remix 14.04 I have the following packages installed:

xorg --no-install-recommends
nodm --no-install-recommends
lxde --no-install-recommends
pulseaudio
alsa-base
hptc-manticore_3.2.1_i386
hptc-rdesktop_1.6.0-1.35_i386
vmware-horizon-view-client_2.3.0-_i386-modified

I added the live user 'ubuntu' to the groups audio, pulse, and pulse-access

aplay -l

```
card0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC9228 Analog [STAC9228 Analog]  
Subdevices: 1/1  
Subdevices #0: subdevice #0  

card0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: STAC9228 Digital [STAC9228 Digital]  
Subdevices: 1/1  
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd

finds a ton of modules and

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

finds

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller  
Subsystem: Dell Device 0209  
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48  
Memory at f6ffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
Capabilities: <access denied>  
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

both

aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

and

sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

play nothing

I have everything unmuted and turned up in alsamixer

I don't have a audio system tray icon but I assume I don't need one

Any insight?

I did nearly the same build on lubuntu live 14.04 and the audio worked fine on all of the same hardware, so I figure I'm missing drivers, modules, packages, or something

thanks

Comment: aplay -l should provide output without the sudo. Permissions?

Comment: I had forgotten to re-log in after joining the user to the appropriate groups, however the result is the same

Comment: I don't follow "find /lib/modules/uname -r | grep snd"
I get find: unknown predicate `-r'

Comment: All support for Ubuntu Mini Remix is provided at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix There doesn't appear to be any action since 2011 Why not use the lubuntu 14.04 live version you had working?

Comment: You have to use ~$ find /lib/modules/\`uname -r\` | grep snd      It was just formatted funny.  Because Lubuntu starts at around 650MB, and I'd like one under 300MB

Comment: Possibly Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54741/only-root-can-play-sounds or http://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi?rq=1

Comment: Possibly useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146245/xfce-volume-adjusting-sound-applet-for-12-04/579774#579774

Comment: It was a matter of adding the live user created on boot to the audio group, it was in one of the casper scripts, I'm not sure which one, but a google search for adding the casper live user to a group should put you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a matter of adding the live user created on boot to the audio group, it was in one of the casper scripts, I'm not sure which one, but a google search for adding the casper live user to a group should put you in the right direction

EDIT:

Sorry, its a simple fix, I was just in a hurry when I responded

in the unpacked rootfs of the live system, you just need to edit the file /etc/adduser.conf such that the adduser command adds the audio group by default.

in the file, make sure to add or edit the ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS line such that it reads:

ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1

and there may or may not be a line which is commented out which lists the extra groups to be added, you may add whichever groups youd like but for just the audio, edit such that it reads:

EXTRA_GROUPS="audio"

to add multiple groups just separate them with spaces within the quotes, like:

EXTRA_GROUPS="audio video plugdev"

Comment: This is a pretty low quality answer, Could you expand on it a bit so that someone else who has the same problem could feasibly benefit? I thank you and the community thanks you.

Comment: ...fixed, sorry